# problem with Spring Security configuration

Tags: java, spring

I'm just starting the adventure with Spring and please to help.

I'm trying to configure Spring Security on a Spring Boot application as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
/*        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());*/

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user"))
                .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/create").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

My controller is:

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String login() {
        return "working";
    }

    @GetMapping("/create")
    public User create() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setPassword("user1");
        user.setEmail("user1@wp.pl");
        user.setName("user1");
        userService.save(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

and my run class:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "main.service, main.repository")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class HomeworkApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HomeworkApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I use POSTMAN to test my endpoint but i gets every time 401.

Someone can help me with this. I spend a lot of time to it and not found solution.

Thanks!

EDIT!!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVlyB.jpg)

Comment: Hi, try to add this after autherizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)

Comment: Hi, the configuration works just fine. did you include username and password in POSTMAN request. is authorization header properly set ?

Comment: @RamachandranMurugaian In POSTMA I use the type Basic Auth and the correct Username and Password

Comment: @RamachandranMurugaian maybe the problem is with DefaultSecurityFilterChain?

Comment: both /create and /users respond with 401? what username and password you use in postman?

Comment: @tashkhisi yes, both gives 401

Comment: what are the username and password you use in postman?

Comment: Username: user Password:user

Comment: Can you please add the package structure of your project ?  I have added sample project in github(https://github.com/chiyanram/security-demo) with your configuration to refer.

Comment: @RamachandranMurugaian Iin my post I added a picture of the project structure

Comment: Can you remove this @ComponentScan(basePackages = "main.service, main.repository") in HomeworkApplication and try ?

Comment: @RamachandranMurugaian It was stupid of me not to check it. I removed ComponentScan and it works. Thanks!

Comment: @KrzysztofSuc I will post this as an answer please accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "main.service, main.repository")` from the `HomeworkApplication`. It is overriding the default componentscan of `SpringBootApplication`.

If you need to scan specific packages add configuration class like below,

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "main.service, main.repository")
@Configuration
public class AppConfig{
}
```